# Video of same length playing faster than the other

Tags: node-editor

Compositor Workspace:

I have two of the same movie clips playing together at the same time but with one displayed under the other due to chroma key issues. For some reason, one is playing faster than the other. What can I do do fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: That is because blender is using frames, convert both of them to an image sequence and choose the same frame rate for both. One of them will be off https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVJ0bw1xNkA&t=86s

Comment: Blender can have problems if the video is encoded using Long GOP (or [interframe compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame)) , where the information for each frame is dependent on other keyframes.. Try to avoid such compression schemes and use intraframe encoding in blender. You might need to transcode your video (using external apps) or convert the video to image sequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render is duplicating random frames when loaded into 3D tracker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185251/render-is-duplicating-random-frames-when-loaded-into-3d-tracker)

Comment: The youtube link you sent me helped and it worked to some degree, but the is still some lag. So I'm trying out a different method, or adjusting/experimenting and I'll see if I can improve anything. Thanks.